# How to store multiple values from a list within a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a list of dictionaries but I want to store 3 values from a dictionary named 'price'

My code is

```
response = yf.Ticker("FB").stats()["price"]
```

output:

```
{'averageDailyVolume10Day': 19621971,
 'averageDailyVolume3Month': 16023089,
 'circulatingSupply': None,
 'currency': 'USD',
 'currencySymbol': '$',
 'exchange': 'NMS',
 'exchangeDataDelayedBy': 0,
 'exchangeName': 'NasdaqGS',
 'fromCurrency': None,
 'lastMarket': None,
 'longName': 'Facebook, Inc.',
 'marketCap': 960766541824,
 'marketState': 'REGULAR',
 'maxAge': 1,
 'openInterest': None,
 'postMarketChange': None,
 'postMarketPrice': None,
 'preMarketChange': 3.51001,
 'preMarketChangePercent': 0.0103239,
 'preMarketPrice': 343.5,
 'preMarketSource': 'FREE_REALTIME',
 'preMarketTime': 1634736599,
 'priceHint': 2,
 'quoteSourceName': 'Nasdaq Real Time Price',
 'quoteType': 'EQUITY',
 'regularMarketChange': 0.7750244,
 'regularMarketChangePercent': 0.0022795508,
 'regularMarketDayHigh': 343.94,
 'regularMarketDayLow': 339.7,
 'regularMarketOpen': 343.445,
 'regularMarketPreviousClose': 339.99,
 'regularMarketPrice': 340.765,
 'regularMarketSource': 'FREE_REALTIME',
 'regularMarketTime': 1634749118,
 'regularMarketVolume': 8538416,
 'shortName': 'Facebook, Inc.',
 'strikePrice': None,
 'symbol': 'FB',
 'toCurrency': None,
 'underlyingSymbol': None,
 'volume24Hr': None,
 'volumeAllCurrencies': None}
```

I would like to get only shortName, regularMarketPrice and symbol

I know that if I want to exctrat one value I should run

```
response = yf.Ticker("FB").stats()["price"]["shortName"]
```

but is there a way to store all 3 values in response?

Comment: `response = [yf.Ticker("FB").stats()["price"]["shortName'], yf.Ticker("FB").stats()["price"]["regularMarketPrice'], yf.Ticker("FB").stats()["price"]["symbol']]` ?

Comment: Thanks RJ Adriaansen, it works, but is there a way to do it without calling stats() multiple times?

Comment: Store `yf.Ticker("FB").stats()["price"]` as a variable first

Comment: The thing is that I already have this running as above but I am trying to find the fastest way to pull the data, as this code is written as a function that runs in loops to get the data of many stocks, so it can take some time. Do you think it's the fastest way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the `output` dictionary you show is stored in `response` variable, you can try this -

```
keys = ['shortName', 'regularMarketPrice', 'symbol']
filtered_response = {k:response.get(k) for k in keys}
```

```
{'shortName': 'Facebook, Inc.', 
 'regularMarketPrice': 340.765, 
 'symbol': 'FB'}
```

Answer (score 0):

@RJ has it right in the comments, but here some explanation for you:

In this case, `yf.Ticker("FB").stats()["price"]["shortName"]` is returning you the entire dictionary.  So all of values are being returned and stored in `response`.

So you can just do:

```py
response = yf.Ticker("FB").stats()["price"]
shortName = response["shortName"]
regularMarketPrice = response["regularMarketPrice"]
symbol = response["symbol"]
```

Comment: The thing is that I already have this running as above but I am trying to find the fastest way to pull the data, as this code is written as a function that runs in loops to get the data of many stocks, so it can take some time. Do you think it's the fastest way?

Comment: If you look at the help for the library, it explains that you can pull multiple symbols at once.

Comment: You should update / replace your question with "How do I get data from Yahoo Finance Faster?" or similar.  We are answering the question you asked, which is simply about getting values from a dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

```py
d = {...}

market_price, name, symbol = [d.get(k) for k in d if k == "regularMarketPrice" or k == "shortName" or k == "symbol"]

print(f'MarketPrice: {market_price}')
print(f'shortName  : {name}')
print(f'symbol     : {symbol}')
```